# Reading from a file with getline never goes past the first line

Tags: c++, file, ifstream, stringstream

I am trying to read the contents of an obj file in C++, and I am struggling with it. It's been a couple of years since I have done anything with C++, so I have forgotten a lot, but I am much more proficient in Java.

I am trying to read an obj file with contents like this

```
# This file uses centimeters as units for non-parametric coordinates.

mtllib crayon.mtl
g default
v 0.927930 -17.363054 -0.279038
...
vt 0.648603 0.107966
... etc
```

However, it doesn't seem to be able to read past the first line. Here is my code thus far:

```
void TextureMapper::read_file(string file_name)
{
    ifstream file;
    file.open(file_name);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        string line;
        while (getline(file, line))
        {
            std::stringstream ss(line);
            string token;
            ss >> token;
            switch (get_obj_type(token))
            {
                case GEOMETRIC_VERTEX:
                    break;
                case TEXTURE_VERTEX:
                    break;
                case VERTEX_NORMAL:
                    break;
                case GROUP_NAME:
                    break;
                case SMOOTHING_GROUP:
                    break;
                case FACE:
                    break;
                case MATERIAL_NAME:
                    break;
                case MATERIAL_LIBRARY:
                    break;
                case COMMENT:
                    break;
                case BLANK:
                    break;
            }
        }
        file.close();
    }
    else
        std::cerr << "Couldn't open " << file_name << " for reading\n";
}
```

Where the enums (`GEOMETRIC_VERTEX`, `GROUP_NAME`, etc) are mapped to the parts of the obj file (like `v`, `g` `vt`, `#`, etc).

**EDIT** I realized the blank line in my file might be causing the exception, so I added an `enum` for that, and added it as a `case` to my `switch` statement, and now I don't get an exception, but it just never reads past the first line.

The first line (`# This file uses centimeters as units ...`) is read in properly, and I can see that when I debug it. However, when it re-enters the `while` loop again, it looks like it re-reads that same line, again and again.

I'm unsure what I am doing incorrectly when I read in this file. Let me know if you need more information to go on.

Comment: Could you encapsulate it in a try & catch and check the exception? Also can we see the code for get_obj_type() function?

Comment: One way to diagnose this problem would be to add a try/catch block.  This will look something like `try
{
   BODY OF MAIN GOES HERE
}
catch (std::exception ex)
{
   std::cerr << ex.message() <, std::endl;
|`

Comment: I've updated the question, and there is no longer an exception. Thanks though.

Comment: Use the 'default' case to be able to proceed with unknown cases in your switch. This would have took into account the blank line case.

Comment: I obviously have to comment out the switch statement to run it. I get the correct first token for each line. Perhaps you should add a function to read_line(const std::string &line) and debug that. It will at least be easy to see the different lines going in.

Comment: So, after some digging, it appears as if the code is indeed working, but the debugger in CLion is not. It correctly goes into the different cases, but it never correctly shows the value of `token` and `line` after the first line of the file.